# Antlr4 exception for empty string match

Tags: c++, antlr, antlr4

My grammar is converted to C++ code. I have the following parser rule:

```
opt_comp_cttnt : separator? (length_restricted | sign | constant | comp_format)+ separator?;

separator : ANY+ ;

# rest for the other rules, they work as expected, so I didnt put them here
```

I would like to use the two optional separators and set them in my protobuffer structure. So my first approach was to use it like this:

```
opt_comp_cttnt         : sep_before = separator? { *_current_component.mutable_separator_before() = $sep_before.text; }
                         (length_restricted | sign | constant | comp_format)+
                         sep_after = separator? { *_current_component.mutable_separator_after() = $sep_after.text; }
```

I was expecting this to either not getting executed when the match was not hit or otherwise `$sep_before.text` to be an empty string. However this threw an exception and when looking at the code I also understand why:

```cpp
*_current_component.mutable_separator_after() = (dynamic_cast<Opt_comp_cttntContext *>(_localctx)->sep_after != nullptr ? _input->getText(dynamic_cast<Opt_comp_cttntContext *>(_localctx)->sep_after->start, dynamic_cast<Opt_comp_cttntContext *>(_localctx)->sep_after->stop) : nullptr);
```

In this case it goes into the second part of the ternary operator which converts `nullptr` into a `std::string`. This is undefined behavior and my C++ runtime decides to throw an exception for this.

So it seems I need to somehow figure out if the text is empty or not without actually getting the text. I already tried to return something from the separator like this:

```
separator              returns[bool has_match = false;]
                       : ANY+ { $has_match = true; };
```

However the `$has_match = true;` for some reason seems to be executed always...

**EDIT**

I just noticed something about the `$has_match` approach.

The following code:

```
sep_after = separator? { *_current_component.mutable_separator_after() = $sep_after.has_match ? $sep_after.text : ""; }
```

Gets translated to this C++ code

```cpp
    if (_la == SwiftMtComponentFormatParser::ANY) {
      setState(63);
      dynamic_cast<Opt_comp_cttntContext *>(_localctx)->sep_after = separator();
    }
     *_current_component.mutable_separator_after() = dynamic_cast<Opt_comp_cttntContext *>(_localctx)->sep_after->has_match ? (dynamic_cast<Opt_comp_cttntContext *>(_localctx)->sep_after != nullptr ? _input->getText(dynamic_cast<Opt_comp_cttntContext *>(_localctx)->sep_after->start, dynamic_cast<Opt_comp_cttntContext *>(_localctx)->sep_after->stop) : nullptr) : "";
```

As you can see `_localctx->sep_after` is only filled if the rule matches, thats why for the `_input->getText` call it first does a check on `_localctx->sep_after != nullptr` however for the `_localctx->sep_after->has_match` no such check is performed and it is accessing a `nullptr`. So it seems to be 2 bugs in antlr I guess.

Comment: I found a workaround, but I dont feel like this is the right answer, which is why I am posting it as a comment: `sep_after = separator? { *_current_component.mutable_separator_after() = ($sep_after.ctx && $sep_after.has_match) ? $sep_after.text : ""; }` which will result in the following code (partial) in the parser: `(dynamic_cast<Opt_comp_cttntContext *>(_localctx)->sep_after && dynamic_cast<Opt_comp_cttntContext *>(_localctx)->sep_after->has_match)`. Now the `nullptr` is checked.

Comment: Don't process your grammar already during the syntactic phase (while you parse the input). Much more flexible (and hence better) is it to use the semantic phase after the parse run to walk the produced parse tree and convert that to your own structures. You could then check if there's a value in specific subrule fields of your RuleContext parameter to see if something was matched or not.